# Table view sqlite data not deleting - iOS - iPad application

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, sqlite

For some reason my data in the database is not deleting, I would be grateful if you can point out the error.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    //Delete
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt2; 
    NSArray *del = [[arr objectAtIndex:row] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *update1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from survey where name='%@' and surname='%@';",[del objectAtIndex:1],[del objectAtIndex:2]];
    int x = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [update1 UTF8String], -1, &stmt2, nil);
    NSLog(@"x=%d",x);
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt2) != SQLITE_DONE)
        NSLog(@"Deletion Error.");

    [arr removeObjectAtIndex:row]; 
    [tblView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that the data from database not deleting or data from tableview not deleting. Please confirm by checking your database(from commandline or sqlite manager).

Here Comes the possible mistakes in your code.
1) Dont pass NSString to sqlite3, pass it like this `const char *query = [queryStr UTF8String];` 
2) make sure that you are finalizing/committing the sqlite statement.

```
sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
```

and also close the sqlite database.

Comment: Hi, it's the data in the database not deleting, it is deleting only on table view. Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell me the value of x being printed. And also there is no need to pass ; along with the query

Comment: AWESOME! i removed the ";" and it worked!! Thank you so much.